# Why do I receive this error when generating a random float?

Tags: c, random

Trying to generate a psuedo-random float btwn 0 and 1. Getting this error when I run the code:

‘RAND_MAX’ undeclared (first use in this function)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(test, numpoints, numtrials, dimension){

    //generate a random number
    srand(time(NULL));
    float r = (float)(rand()/RAND_MAX +1);


    printf("%.6f", r);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Sorry--accidentally cut it before pasting it into stackoverflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. To use [`RAND_MAX`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/RAND_MAX) in C, you need to include its header:

   ```
   #include <stdlib.h>
   ```
2. `rand()/RAND_MAX` is an integer division, if you want floating division, you should covert it to `float` first, then divide:  `(float)(rand()) / RAND_MAX`
3. You need to define your main as:

   ```
   int main ( int arc, char **argv )
   ```

Comment: There are bigger problems.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Please explain the details.

Comment: This is true.  Now I'm only getting 0.0000

Comment: Did you look at the definition of `main`?

Answer (score 1):

`RAND_MAX` is within `stdlib`. You'll need to include it.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

`(rand() / RAND_MAX)` is an integer division, and will equal zero. You then add 1, and then convert to float, giving you 1.0.  If you want floating division, you have to covert first, then divide:  `(float)(rand()) / RAND_MAX` . . .

Plus, you're not including `stdlib`, and your arguments to `main` are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing stdlib.h.  Thats what is needed in C++ but I am not entirely sure about C.